# Python - how to substitute a substring using regex with n occurrencies

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with a lot of recurrencies of a single pattern like

```
a = 'eresQQQutnohnQQQjkhjhnmQQQlkj'
```

and I have another string like

```
b = 'rerTTTytu'
```

I want to substitute the *entire* second string having as a reference the 'QQQ' and the 'TTT', and I want to find in this case 3 different results:

```
'ererTTTytuohnQQQjkhjhnmQQQlkj'
'eresQQQutnrerTTTytujhnmQQQlkj'
'eresQQQutnohnQQQjkhjrerTTTytu'
```

I've tried using re.sub

```
re.sub('\w{3}QQQ\w{3}' ,b,a)
```

but I obtain only the first one, and I don't know how to get the other two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: As you requested, the two characters surrounding 'QQQ' will be replaced as well now.**

I don't know if this is the most elegant or simplest solution for the problem, but it works:

```
import re

# Find all occurences of ??QQQ?? in a - where ? is any character
matches = [x.start() for x in re.finditer('\S{2}QQQ\S{2}', a)]
# Replace each ??QQQ?? with b
results = [a[:idx] + re.sub('\S{2}QQQ\S{2}', b, a[idx:], 1) for idx in matches]

print(results)
```

**Output**

```
['errerTTTytunohnQQQjkhjhnmQQQlkj',
'eresQQQutnorerTTTytuhjhnmQQQlkj',
'eresQQQutnohnQQQjkhjhrerTTTytuj']
```

Since you didn't specify the output format, I just put it in a list.

Comment: The problem that I have to change also the two characters before and the two after in the original string, you keeped them in the final string.

Comment: I just updated my answer - the two character before "QQQ" and after it will be replaced as well. Please try to add easier to read examples in your question in the future. It is really difficult to figure out what you're trying to do from a random string of characters.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for my next question!

Thank you very much!